# Mysql и Lazarus

Tags: mysql, lazarus

Какой код для лазаруса нужно написать , чтобы потом при запросе символы поменялись на `UTF-8`?

[image: таблица[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Если как-то так?

```
conn := TMySQL50Connection.Create(nil);
TMySQL50Connection.CharSet:='UTF8';
```

и еще запрос попробовать, перед выборкой

```
query.SQL.Text := 'SET CHARACTER SET `utf8`';
```